# Is there something similar to R's brglm to help deal with quasi-separation in Python using statsmodels Logit?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am using Logit from statsmodels to create a regression model.

I get the error: LinAlgError: Singular matrix and then when I remove 1 variable at a time from my dataset, I finally got a different error: PerfectSeparationError: Perfect separation detected, results not available.

I suspect that the original error (LinAlgError) is related to perfect separation because I had the same problem in R and got around it using a brglm (bias reduced glm).

I have a boolean y variable and 23 numeric and boolean x variables.

I have already run a VIF function to remove any variables which have high multicollinearity scores (I started with 26 variables).

I have tried using the firth_regression.py instead to account for perfect separation but I got a memory error: MemoryError.(https://gist.github.com/johnlees/3e06380965f367e4894ea20fbae2b90d)

I have tried the LogisticRegression from sklearn but cannot get the p values which is no good to me.

I even tried removing 1 variable at a time from my dataset.  When I got down to 4 variables left (I had 23), then I got PerfectSeparationError: Perfect separation detected, results not available.

Has anyone experienced this and how do you get around it?

Appreciate any advice!

```
    X = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'VehicleMake']
    y = df.iloc[:,0]
    # Split data
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = skl.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
```

Code in question:

```
    # Perform logistic regression and get p values
    logit_model = sm.Logit(y_train, X_train.astype(float))
    result = logit_model.fit()
```

This is the firth_regression I tried instead which got me a memory error:

```
# For the firth_regression
import sys
import warnings
import math
import statsmodels
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf


def firth_likelihood(beta, logit):
    return -(logit.loglike(beta) + 0.5*np.log(np.linalg.det(-logit.hessian(beta))))

step_limit=1000
convergence_limit=0.0001

logit_model = smf.Logit(y_train, X_train.astype(float))

start_vec = np.zeros(X.shape[1])

beta_iterations = []
beta_iterations.append(start_vec)
for i in range(0, step_limit):
    pi = logit_model.predict(beta_iterations[i])
    W = np.diagflat(np.multiply(pi, 1-pi))
    var_covar_mat = np.linalg.pinv(-logit_model.hessian(beta_iterations[i]))

    # build hat matrix
    rootW = np.sqrt(W)
    H = np.dot(np.transpose(X_train), np.transpose(rootW))
    H = np.matmul(var_covar_mat, H)
    H = np.matmul(np.dot(rootW, X), H)

    # penalised score
    U = np.matmul(np.transpose(X_train), y - pi + np.multiply(np.diagonal(H), 0.5 - pi))
    new_beta = beta_iterations[i] + np.matmul(var_covar_mat, U)

    # step halving
    j = 0
    while firth_likelihood(new_beta, logit_model) > firth_likelihood(beta_iterations[i], logit_model):
        new_beta = beta_iterations[i] + 0.5*(new_beta - beta_iterations[i])
        j = j + 1
        if (j > step_limit):
            sys.stderr.write('Firth regression failed\n')
            None

    beta_iterations.append(new_beta)
    if i > 0 and (np.linalg.norm(beta_iterations[i] - beta_iterations[i-1]) < convergence_limit):
        break

return_fit = None
if np.linalg.norm(beta_iterations[i] - beta_iterations[i-1]) >= convergence_limit:
    sys.stderr.write('Firth regression failed\n')
else:
# Calculate stats
    fitll = -firth_likelihood(beta_iterations[-1], logit_model)
    intercept = beta_iterations[-1][0]
    beta = beta_iterations[-1][1:].tolist()
    bse = np.sqrt(np.diagonal(-logit_model.hessian(beta_iterations[-1])))

    return_fit = intercept, beta, bse, fitll
#print(return_fit)
```

Comment: statsmodels does not have Firth penalized models yet, but has elastic net or L2 penalized GLM. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by changing the default method in the logit regression to method ='bfgs'.

```
result = logit_model.fit(method = 'bfgs')
```

Answer (score 0):

Few years late for this question, but I'm working on a [Python implementation of Firth logistic regression](https://github.com/jzluo/firthlogist) using the procedure detailed in the R logistf package and [Heinze and Schemper, 2002](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12210625/). There are a few implementation differences compared to the gist you linked that make it much more memory efficient, and p-values are calculated using penalized likelihood ratio tests. Confidence intervals are also calculated.

Obviously I don't have your data, so let's use the `sex2` dataset included with the `logistf` R package.

```
>>> from firthlogist import FirthLogisticRegression, load_sex2
>>> fl = FirthLogisticRegression()
>>> X, y, feature_names = load_sex2()
>>> fl.fit(X, y)
FirthLogisticRegression()
>>> fl.summary(xname=feature_names)
                 coef    std err     [0.025      0.975]      p-value
---------  ----------  ---------  ---------  ----------  -----------
age        -1.10598     0.42366   -1.97379   -0.307427   0.00611139
oc         -0.0688167   0.443793  -0.941436   0.789202   0.826365
vic         2.26887     0.548416   1.27304    3.43543    1.67219e-06
vicl       -2.11141     0.543082  -3.26086   -1.11774    1.23618e-05
vis        -0.788317    0.417368  -1.60809    0.0151846  0.0534899
dia         3.09601     1.67501    0.774568   8.03028    0.00484687
Intercept   0.120254    0.485542  -0.818559   1.07315    0.766584

Log-Likelihood: -132.5394
Newton-Raphson iterations: 8
```

Compare results with `brglm`:

```
> library(brglm)
Loading required package: profileModel
'brglm' will gradually be superseded by the 'brglm2' R package (https://cran.r-project.org/package=brglm2), which provides utilities for mean and median bias reduction for all GLMs.
 Methods for the detection of separation and infinite estimates in binomial-response models are provided by the 'detectseparation' R package (https://cran.r-project.org/package=detectseparation).
> fit <- brglm(case~age+oc+vic+vicl+vis+dia, data=logistf::sex2)
> summary(fit)

Call:
brglm(formula = case ~ age + oc + vic + vicl + vis + dia, data = logistf::sex2)


Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.12025    0.48554   0.248 0.804390    
age         -1.10598    0.42366  -2.611 0.009040 ** 
oc          -0.06882    0.44379  -0.155 0.876770    
vic          2.26887    0.54842   4.137 3.52e-05 ***
vicl        -2.11141    0.54308  -3.888 0.000101 ***
vis         -0.78832    0.41737  -1.889 0.058921 .  
dia          3.09601    1.67501   1.848 0.064551 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 304.61  on 238  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 276.91  on 232  degrees of freedom
Penalized deviance: 265.0788 
AIC:  290.91
```

The p-values are slightly different because they are calculated by penalized likelihood ratio tests, whereas `brglm` uses Wald tests. firthlogist can also use Wald:

```
>>> fl = FirthLogisticRegression(wald=True)
>>> fl.fit(X, y)
FirthLogisticRegression(wald=True)
>>> fl.summary(xname=feature_names)
                 coef    std err     [0.025      0.975]      p-value
---------  ----------  ---------  ---------  ----------  -----------
age        -1.10598     0.42366   -1.93634   -0.275623   0.00903995
oc         -0.0688167   0.443793  -0.938636   0.801002   0.87677
vic         2.26887     0.548416   1.194      3.34375    3.51659e-05
vicl       -2.11141     0.543082  -3.17583   -1.04699    0.000101147
vis        -0.788317    0.417368  -1.60634    0.0297084  0.0589208
dia         3.09601     1.67501   -0.186943   6.37896    0.0645508
Intercept   0.120254    0.485542  -0.83139    1.0719     0.80439

Log-Likelihood: -132.5394
Newton-Raphson iterations: 8
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).